# Redirect all traffic regardless of port or protocol to temporary page

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, tomcat6, maintenance

I have a server with multiple domains. Both http (apache) traffic and http-alt (tomcat) traffic.

If/when I take the server down, I'd like to be able to redirect people to a temporary 'undergoing maintenance' page, regardless of their destination URL/port.

How can this be achieved? Do I need tomcat running on the secondary server or is there a way to catch all and redirect via some method I'm not aware of? I've tried simply forcing all 80/8080 traffic to the secondary server, but depending on the URL it doesn't resolve, and it never resolves when trying to access :8080/whatever. Any ideas?

**EDIT (update)**: I have successfully achieved this catch all for any domain and anything port 80 traffic using [`_default_ vhost`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#default), but it's still not catching anything on 8080, even though I am specifying:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName host
    ServerAlias *
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Anyone know why or how to?

**EDIT (update 2)**: using tomcat's [`error-code`](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q6)

in /etc/tomcat/web.xml I added

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/index.html</location>
</error-page>
```

I am able to get it to work now for the root of tomcat http://domain.com:8080 but nothing for any general 404 like http://domain.com:8080/nonexistentpath

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Use IP Tables, not you Apache config. I would give more information, but I'm no expert. Take a look at http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/.

Comment: Thanks, it actually is working now. I changed `/WEB-INF/index.html` to `/index.html` and also added the `<error-code>500</error-code>` as well. I will look into using IP Tables as well, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in my updates to the question and stated in the comments above:

To handle the port Apache (port 80) 404's, I used the following in the Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName host
    ServerAlias *
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

To handle them in Tomcat (8080, in my case), in `/etc/tomcat/web.xml` i added:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
</error-page>
```

The only other problem I came across is that the tomcat 404 would not display on IE. I ended up needing to [add additional data to the page](http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/IE-9-ignoring-my-custom-error-pages-with-404-codes-td4974071.html) in form of comments to add some weight to the file for IE to display my custom page instead of it's own. How silly.

I hope this helps someone else, in the future.